# iptables not routing ssh correctly

Tags: iptables

Im working on AWS systems, setting up my own little network.

I have an AWS Load Balancer in an open subnet.  In the subnet with the load balancer is a nano size server, running Apache that is acting as my poor mans proxy server routing to my DMZ subnet.  I had that working great, routing to HTTPS and everything.  It was a thing of simplistic beauty.

Then came the cause of my current pain.

One of my machines in my DMZ is a gitlab server.  Git requires SSH access for cloning and such.  Since im running apache, because I know apache and can configure it blindfolded, I needed to forward the SSH.  Since this one machine is the only one that needs SSH from the outside, i figured piece of cake, iptables port forward.

So after about 5 hours of trying to get IP Tables to forward correctly, I begin a full system test and realize somehow my machine can ONLY accept port 22.  Which is really bad.  Even from curl locally, i can't access apache.  Im giving up for the day, but do any of you masters see anything in my iptables config that would shut down http and https access to the proxy machine?

I think my problem is the forward statement in the output section.  I think whats happening is that forward statement is forwarding ALL traffic to that .69:22 port.  Problem is that statement was key to making the SSH stuff forward.

proxy machine = 10.0.0.5

gitlab = 10.0.1.69

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.18 on Sun Aug 14 01:06:58 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [326:116424]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [306:122290]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j LOG
-A FORWARD -d 10.0.0.5/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j LOG
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Aug 14 01:06:58 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.18 on Sun Aug 14 01:06:58 2016
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [112:6680]
:INPUT ACCEPT [112:6680]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [54:3304]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [54:3304]
-A PREROUTING -d 10.0.0.5/32 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.69:22
-A POSTROUTING -d 10.0.1.69/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.5
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Aug 14 01:06:58 2016
```

Comment: You may have to enable forwarding with sysctl.  Try using a firewall builder.

Comment: i did enable forwarding.  I would have never been able to get the ssh to forward without it.  And which firewall builder?  I've been looking around for some config file builder for a while but havn't found one that has been updated in the past 3 years.

Comment: What are the interfaces of those IP addresses? What does `iptables -nvl` show when the configuration is active? I use Shorewall to build firewalls. FIrewalls are quite stable technology that updates are not that needed.